# Pass Direct View Ref To Native Module

Tags: android, react-native

I'm looking to implement a [React Native native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) that directly manipulates a given View reference, namely by transforming it with a natively implemented animation.

Is it possible to pass View references to native modules, and if so how could one do this?

Ideally the JavaScript API would be akin to this:

```
var animation = require("NativeModules").animation;

...

animation.foo(this.refs.hello);
```

If not, are there alternatives like utilizing [Native UI Components](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html#content)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so from digging into the source I found the [UI Manager class](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/UIManagerModule.java).

Obtain a reference to it in the native code, and invoke `.registerAnimation()` with an [Animation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/animation/Animation.java) implementation (not sure where the `int animationID` comes from yet!?).

<strike>The animation will be passed a View ref directly to manipulate in the `.run()` method.</strike>

The Animation constructor is passed an [AnimationPropertyUpdater](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/animation/AnimationPropertyUpdater.java) implementation that will affect the View ref directly in its methods.

So I guess for now I will try to use the existing React Native UI Manager API seeing as it has private knowledge of the View hierarchy internally. Will update this answer with any more findings